# Desktop file for bash script

Tags: bash, .desktop

I have a .desktop file for a bash script, but when I launch the .desktop file nothing happens except that a terminal window is shown for half a second.

If I run the bash script directly (without the .desktop file), the script works fine (bash file is called 'minecraft'):

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -cp minecraft.jar net.minecraft.LauncherFrame
```

The file is executable.

This is my minecraft.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Minecraft
Comment=Minecraft
Icon=/home/bram/Applications/Minecraft/icon.png
Exec=/home/bram/Applications/Minecraft/minecraft
Terminal=true
Categories=Minecraft;game
```

minecraft.desktop is located in ~/.local/share/applications

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. You should move it to an answer and accept it, though, so your question shows up as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the script couldn't find the .jar file.
When I run the bash file using the .desktop file, I assume it runs the bash file in the directory of the .desktop file (~/.local/share/applications).

When I give the full path name to the jar, it works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -cp /home/bram/Applications/Minecraft/minecraft.jar net.minecraft.LauncherFrame
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1.) Set the working directory in the .desktop file to the location of the .jar

2.) Use full paths in your Bash script (like you did)

Comment: How do you "set the working directory in the .desktop file" @user241583 ? I tried using `WorkingDirectory=...` and validator complained I was extending the spec without using an `X-` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it as a background task:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -cp minecraft.jar net.minecraft.LauncherFrame
```

(Note the `nohup` at the beginning used to make keep running)

Comment: Still nothing happens. The jar still isn't launched.

Comment: Try removing the space right before the &.

Comment: No, still nothing..

Comment: OK... Do you mind the script running at all times?

Comment: Yes, the script opens a jar file (which is a game) and I don't want the game to be running all the time.

Comment: Ah. Please try edits to my post, coming in a minute...

Comment: OK. It's good everything worked.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. But it helped me find the solution, I'll post it in a minute. It generated a log file nohup.out with the error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.LauncherFrame