# how to provide a localized text file that opens within the language that gnome runs

Tags: gnome, 10.04, locale

I need to provide to my users a localized text file that would open (from a desktop icon) in the language that gnome is running. How I do that ?

I am running Lucid Ubuntu

Thanks !!

Comment: 10.04? It is supported, but I would seriously upgrade to a better version.

Comment: @nerof61 : this is a specific system with specific hardware. Not my desktop OS :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to check the value of the `LANG` environment variable:

```
user@host:~$ echo $LANG
en_GB.UTF-8
```

You can then write a short script which picks an appropriate file based on the value of this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SHORTLANG=${LANG:0:2}
zenity --text-info --filename greeting_${SHORTLANG}.txt
```

Which takes the first two characters of `$LANG` and displays the appropriate textfile - `greeting_en.txt` etc.

Finally, create a [desktop link to this script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176113/desktop-file-for-bash-script).

(Adjust the length of the `SHORTLANG` string if you're interested in the difference between `en_GB` and `en_US` rather than just the difference between `fr` and `de`).